# How are the differential forms in $S^1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I'm really confused about differential forms in Manifolds.

I know that the usual differential forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be like for example

$dx_1+dx_2+dx_3+...$ ($1-form$)

$dx_1\wedge dx_3+dx_2\wedge dx_4+dx_3\wedge dx_4+...$ ($2-form$) , etc.

But how looks a differential form in $S^1$?

Comment: You may first want to understand the notion of *charts*. They translate local parts of manifolds to part of $\Bbb R^n$, so that your familiar $dx_i$'s can apply.

Comment: @WhatsUp I was reading a bit about it. If i have a chart $(U,\varphi)$ on a manifold with coordinates $\varphi=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ then the differential forms of the manifold looks like $da_1 \wedge da_2$, or $da_1+da_2$, etc. ??

Comment: so, $\varphi :\ ]0,2\pi[\hookrightarrow\!S^1$ given by $\varphi(a_1)=(\cos a_1,\sin a_1)^{\top}$ is a local chart.